# How can you detect whether a call result is valid

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr, type-traits

I'm trying to create a trait that detects whteher type Apply has a valid result when called with 2 arguments. I would expect the static_assert in the code not to hit because the result of apply is a valid one (dividing float). Why does this assert hit, and how would I change the trait in such a way that all the valid overloads for apply are detected as true_type or constexpr bool true.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

struct Apply
{
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    float apply(const T1& a, const T2& b) const
    {
        return a / b;
    }
};

struct ApplyInvoker
{
    Apply a;

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        return a.apply(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <class Void, class... T>
struct ValidCall : std::false_type
{ 
};
template <class... T>
struct ValidCall<
    std::void_t<decltype(std::invoke(std::declval<ApplyInvoker>(), std::declval<T>()...))>, 
    T...> 
    : std::true_type
{ 
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr bool CanApply = ValidCall<void, T1, T2>::value;

int main()
{
    static_assert(CanApply<float, float>);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using your template as:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr bool CanApply = ValidCall<T1, T2>::value;
```

But the primary is declared as:

```
template <class Void, class... T>
struct ValidCall;
```

That first template parameter is named `Void` because it *has* to be `void` - that's what the specialization is matching against. So you have to do it this way:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr bool CanApply = ValidCall<void, T1, T2>::value;
//                                  ^~~~
```

---

But also, this is C++17, and we have a type trait for that:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr bool CanApply = std::is_invocable_v<ApplyInvoker, T1, T2>;
```

---

The problem is that neither `Apply` nor `ApplyInvoker` actually work with type traits. `Apply` advertises itself as being invocable with any two arguments - there is no way to detect otherwise. `ApplyInvoker` advertises itself as being invocable with any number of arguments - but in a way that will lead to a hard compiler error if you try to find out with the wrong set of them. Both these types are what we would call SFINAE-unfriendly - they're not friendly to type traits, they're not testable.

If you want them to actually be testable, then you need to rewrite both as follows:

```
struct Apply
{
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    float apply(const T1& a, const T2& b) const
        -> decltype(float(a / b))
    {
        return a / b;
    }
};

struct ApplyInvoker
{
    Apply a;

    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args)
        -> decltype(a.apply(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
        return a.apply(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Or something similar.

Comment: std::is_invocable_v does not compile for calls to apply that are invalid (where no operator / is defined), i would like to get false when it can't apply. Maybe more similar to the detection of members...

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe `std::is_invocable_v` checks if `std::invoke` is possible - which is the same trait you're writing. It _does_ return false when the type isn't invocable with the arguments, that's its point.

Comment: Yeah I was trying something similar but I havent figured it out yet, I want it to compile for CanApply<string, float> for example but return me false instead of not compiling.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe On the other hand, your `ApplyInvoker` is always invocable with all arguments. That's `ApplyInvoker`'s problem, not `std::is_invocable`'s.

Comment: Since there will be alot of versions of the apply class im trying to do the sfinae outside of the function as you will and not call it when it would result in undefined.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe You can't do sfinae outside of the function - the function has to advertise its own constraints.